# Why is 1e100 not exactly representable as 64 bit float?

Tags: floating-point, computer-science, precision, numerical-methods

I have been told that 1e100 is not exactly representable as a 64 bit floating point number. With a 64 bit floating point number, we can have 16 significant digits in the significand, and manipulate the exponent (up to about 10^308). Thus, as 1e100 has only one significant digit, why is this number not exactly representable as a floating point number?

Comment: examine what it takes to represent 100, 1000, 10000, and then answer becomes obvious very fast.

Comment: Its a topic from computer science that if you really want to know then you have to dig into the math. Otherwise - you just believe it (only powers of two can be represented in floating point) - see: [why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate), [floating point arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf), [floatingpoint](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and hundreds of articles like them (long and short)

Comment: floating point is base 2 not base 10.

Answer (score 3):

`1e100` or 10<sup>100</sup> is the same as 2<sup>100</sup> * 5<sup>100</sup>.

5<sup>100</sup>, an odd number, is a 233 bit integer, far beyond the precision capabilities of a common 64-bit [*binary* floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) - which often has 53 bits of precision.  Each binary floating point has an exact value that is some integer times a power of 2.

If we are using a less common [*decimal* floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal64_floating-point_format) encoding, no problem to save 10<sup>100</sup> exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point uses exponents of 2 not 10.

```
10^100 ~ 1.1429873912822749822157835483053 x 2^332.
```

---

Conversely, though 2^332 has 99 significant digits, it can be represented exactly as a float.

Comment: might be worth pointing out that the f64 nearest to 1e100 is exactly `5147557589468029 * 2^(332-52)`, and matches to the expected 16 decimal places.  `5147557589468029 * (2^-52)` matches your `1.14..., but your decimal approximation might be obscuring the representation

Comment: @SamMason: no, the floating-point representation uses a mantissa that exceeds 1, not the nearest approximation. Also, showing an integer seems to imply an exact value. Your comment is obscuring things.